# Wiredep and useminPrepare cant handle multiple src

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower, wiredep

In short, I use grunt wiredep and useminPrepare. I want to merge some of my bower dependencies into single file.

**HTML Markup**

```
<!-- build:js js/vendor/libraries.min.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/velocity/velocity.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/velocity/velocity.ui.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**Wiredep config**

```
    wiredep: {
        target: {
            src: [
                '<%= app %>/**/*.html'
            ],
            exclude: [
                'modernizr',
                'Tabslet',
                'velocity'
            ]
        }
    }
```

**useMin and useMinPrepare config**

```
    useminPrepare: {
        html: ['<%= app %>/*.html'],
        options: {
            dest: '<%= dist %>'
        }
    },

    usemin: {
        html: ['<%= dist %>/**/*.html', '!<%= app %>/bower_components/**'],
        css: ['<%= dist %>/css/**/*.css'],
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= dist %>']
        }
    },
```

The problem is that in libraries.min.js, there's only jQuery included.

Comment: You're using Blocs https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#blocks but do <!-- bower:js --> is the problem in you HTML?

Comment: Forgot about mentioning the issue itself - in libraries.min.js there's only jQuery included, instead of those 3 packages.

Comment: Ahah, ok. But still, what `<!-- bower:js -->` is it for?

Comment: Wiredep need this markup to load all dependency src. In the "clean" project there's nothing between bower comments, after wiredep is ran, those script src are added based on bower.json file

Comment: Sorry I don't have experience with yeoman, but when I look the documentation, it seems that the configuration is also made js side (and it looks strange and not efficient)

Comment: Well it doesn't particulary have anything to do with yeoman :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `'velocity'` from wiredep `exclude:` to solve your problem.
Moreover, according to grunt-usemin documentation, the option `dirs:` doesn't exist, you might want to mean `assetsDirs:`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-usemin